# A simple question about syntax

Tags: verbs, expressions, word-order, negation

I guess this would be a pretty simple question to answer. Is this sentence correct:

> The player appears to have not connected.

I am having my doubts about the *appears to have not* part.

P.S.: Not quite sure what tags to put in, feel free to edit.

Comment: What exactly bothers you about this sentence? It's a less common stylistic variant of *...does not appear to have connected*, but both versions are perfectly valid English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't sure if such word order was correct. Thanks for clearing that out for me :)

Comment: You'd probably do better asking any future questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where answers are more likely to be tailored to the needs of non-native speakers. I think what you *really* want to know probably isn't "Is this grammatical?" so much as "When and why might people use this form, rather than one involving *do-support*?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentence

- *The player appears to have **not** connected.*

*connected* is the focus of negation, and thus *not* can appear directly before it, as here.

However, *not* can **also** appear directly before the beginning of any constituent containing its focus.

*Connected* is in the [Verb Phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) *have connected*, so *not* can go before that, too

- *The player appears to **not** have connected.*

and also in the [Infinitive Complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Complements.pdf) *to have connected*, so *not* can go before that, too

- *The player appears **not** to have connected.*

Since *appear* is a [Neg-Raising](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/185419/15299) verb (i.e, it's transparent to negation), *not* can **also** negate
the complex VP constituent *appears to have been connected*.

This, of course, requires *Do*-Support, because *appears* is present tense, and negating a tensed verb
requires an auxiliary verb to carry the tense. When there's no auxiliary verb already in the tensed VP to be negated, one uses *Do*.  That's [*Do*-Support;](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299) i.e,

- *The player **does not** appear to have connected*,
  or, more likely
- *The player **doesn't** appear to have connected*.

They're all grammatical, and they all mean the same thing.
And I didn't even mention [A-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

I would use:

*The player appears not to have connected*

or

*The player does not appear to have connected*