# about 'couldn't'

Tags: negation, auxiliary-verbs, subordinate-clauses

Does anyone know what's wrong with 'couldn't' in the following?

> 1. I think there **couldn’t** be any trains today due to the strike, so I’m going by bus.

What's interesting is that,

> 2. There **couldn't** be any trains today due to the strike.

is ok.

Does anyone know why the addition of ***'I think'*** in #1 makes it odd?

Comment: To want to use "*won't*" instead.

Comment: The tenses should be consistent - either *"I **think** there **can't** be any trains today"*, or *"I **thought** there **couldn't** be any trains yesterday"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, not sure about that: *It is clear that there couldn't be a train strike today*.

Comment: @Araucaria: I only said *should*, not *must*. There are contexts where the tenses can quite reasonably be mixed (either way round). So strictly speaking the question is based on a false premise, since there's nothing actually "wrong". But I can't see anything else that would justify calling OP's example "odd".

Comment: 'There couldn't be any trains today' doesn't sound as idiomatic as 'There could be some trains today'. I'd switch to 'There may not be any trains today' or 'No trains were able to run today, ...', whichever is meant.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with "would" in the example, with or without preceding "I think".

Comment: @FumbleFingers The reason it's odd is because of the fact that we prefer [*subordinate negation implication*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177675/is-there-a-functional-difference-between-not-believing-and-believing-not/177699#177699) with the verb *think*. So the sentence *I don't think there could be any trains today, due to the strike* comes out ok :)

Comment: @Araucaria: Ah. You're quite right. I'd still prefer *"I **don't** think there **can** be any trains today"*, but the "less common" negation is probably the biggest cause of "oddness" (such as it is, which isn't much).

Answer (score 3):

In English, we prefer to negate the verb *think* rather than to use a negative in the content clause which represents the actual thought involved. This is also true with verbs like *want* and *believe*. So we prefer:

- I don't think she's here

to

- I think she isn't here.

And we prefer:

- I don't want to eat it

to

- I want to not eat it.

I think that the problem with the sentence:

- I think there couldn't be any trains running today due to the strike

doesn't really have anything to do with the verb *could* - although it is tempting, and indeed not unreasonable to think so. The real problem is that we would far rather negate the verb *think* than the verb phrase in the subordinate clause - which in this instance is headed by the auxiliary verb *could*:

- I don't think there could be any trains running today because of the strike.

The sentence above seems fine in spite of the verb *could*.

If you're interested in *subordinate negation implication*, [you can read more about it here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177675/is-there-a-functional-difference-between-not-believing-and-believing-not/177699#177699)

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: +1. Also, this topic is discussed in the 2002 *CGEL* in its section "Increased specificity of negation (*I don't want to hear abut it*)".

Comment: BBC says the following:  http://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/english/course/lower-intermediate/unit-16/tab/grammar


WRONG: I think there couldn’t be any trains today, so I’m going by bus.
CORRECT: I think there mightn’t be any trains today, so I’m going by bus.

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, that's because like *can't*, *couldn't* has wide scope negation. So *couldn't* and *can't* rule out any possibility. They can't be used to mean *it's possible that not*, they mean *it's not possible*. That lesson's about talking about *possibility*. So if you want to say it's possible the trains aren't running you need to say "I think there mightn’t be any trains". If you say *couldn't* or *can't* it means there definitely are no trains running ...

Comment: @Apollyon ... also subordinate negation implication won't work in negative sentences which have any items with modal meanings indicating possibility (for example *might* *may* *maybe* *perhaps etc*) So *I don't think perhaps she'll go* doesn't mean *I think perhaps she won't go*. But in normal sentences it's fine: *I don't think she'll go* does usually mean *I think she won't go*. Interesting, ins't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue of saying, thinking and saying what is being thought!  When you think, you think 'there couldn't be trains today because of the strike'.  When you say (what you think), you would say, '(I think) there wouldn't be trains today because of the strike'.